# How to create n Object base on DataTable.Rows.Count in C#?

Tags: c#, multithreading, linq, datatable

All code below only to create two processes. While I need to create n process to open Chrome browser and run `OpenNRowsInData(user, pwd)` based on `dtUser.Rows.Count` because this is dynamic.

And I don't know why `OpenNRowsInData(user, pwd);` always only get first rows.

I have a `DataTable` range from 1-7 rows.

Typically, I was usually using to create two objects.

```
static myObject[] browser = new myObject[] { 
          new myObject(Browsers.Chrome, 0), 
          new myObject(Browsers.Chrome, 0)
};

Thread t1, t2;

t1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(AllCase))
{
    Name = "Thread1"
};
t1.Start();

t2 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(AllCase))
{
    Name = "Thread2"
};
t2.Start();
```

In class `AllCase`:

```
static int[] stepRun = { 0, 0 };
private void AllCase()
{
    int idx = int.Parse(Thread.CurrentThread.Name.Replace("Thread", "")) - 1;
    switch (stepRun[idx])
    {
        case 0:
            foreach (DataRow row in dtUser.Rows)
            {
                user = row["user"].ToString();
                pwd = row["pwd"].ToString();
                OpenNRowsInData(user, pwd);
            }
            break;
        case 1:
            ClickBuy();
            break;
    }
}
```

And in another, before I using parallel process. Currently, I don't want to use it.

```
Parallel.ForEach(
    dtUser.AsEnumerable(),
    items => OpenNRowsInData(items["user"].ToString(), items["pwd"].ToString()));
```

I want to get only columns `user` and `pwd`.

Tried with code, I tried to add a parameter in `action()` method like: `action(string user, string pwd)`.

```
public static void ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Action<T> action)
{
    if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
    if (action == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("action");

    foreach (T item in source)
    {
        action(item);
    }
}
```

**Updated:**

Add class `OpenNRowsInData(string username, string password)`:

```
private void OpenNRowsInData(string username, string password)
{
    int idx = int.Parse(Thread.CurrentThread.Name.Replace("Thread", "")) - 1;
    try
    {
        browser[idx].DeleteAllCookies();
        browser[idx].GoToUrl(link);
        browser[idx].waittingID("txtUserName", 15);
        browser[idx].FindElementById("txtUserName").SendKeys(username);
        browser[idx].FindElementById("txtpassword").SendKeys(password);
        browser[idx].FindElementById("btnlogin").Click();
        stepRun[idx] = 1;
        AllCase();
    }
}
```

Comment: could you post the implementation of `OpenNRowsInData()` ?

Comment: Your question is why does `OpenNRowsInData(user, pwd);` always only get first rows..?=! Just for clarification: in `dtUser.Rows` you have 7 rows, so 7 users and you want to login each of them. When you step through the foreach loop in `AllCase` does it yield the right `user` and `pwd` values?

Comment: does the loop exit after the first iteration? or does it give you 7 times the same row?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120405/discussion-between-vn-lc-and-mong-zhu).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> And I don't know why OpenNRowsInData(user, pwd); always only get first rows.

It seems for me that your second threat is too fast. Before the first can finish it will execute `ClickBuy();` so only the first row can be processed.

try to do it one step after the other

```
AllCase(0, 0);
AllCase(1, 0);


private void AllCase(int case, int browserNr)
{
    switch (case)
    {
        case 0:
            foreach (DataRow row in dtUser.Rows)
            {
                user = row["user"].ToString();
                pwd = row["pwd"].ToString();
                OpenNRowsInData(user, pwd, browserNr);
            }
            break;
        case 1:
            ClickBuy();
            break;
    }
}

private void OpenNRowsInData(string username, string password, int browserNr)
{      
    try
    {
        browser[browserNr].DeleteAllCookies();
        browser[browserNr].GoToUrl(link);
        browser[browserNr].waittingID("txtUserName", 15);
        browser[browserNr].FindElementById("txtUserName").SendKeys(username);
        browser[browserNr].FindElementById("txtpassword").SendKeys(password);
        browser[browserNr].FindElementById("btnlogin").Click();
    }
}
```

If you want to do it for both browsers try running a loop on the array:

```
for(int j = 0; j < browser.Length;j++)
{
    AllCase(0, j);
    AllCase(1, j);
}
```

This time parallelisation would actually pay off. Because you could do the same stuff in both browsers at the same time, but it seems you should not do both `AllCase` - cases in **the same** browser at the same time, because they are consecutive

**EDIT:**

After your edit it seems that when you go in your loop the first time you set in `OpenNRowsInData` at the position `0`

```
stepRun[idx] = 1;
```

and then call again

```
AllCase();
```

this time it will execute

```
    case 1:
        ClickBuy();
        break;
```

on the second iteration it will try again to switch on

```
switch (stepRun[idx])
```

but this time it will find a `1` on the position `0` in `stepRun`. For all 
and never go back in the case to call `OpenNRowsInData`.
This is why you get only the first row.

**EDIT 2:**

if you want to do it at the same time in both browsers you can make a routine that executes the two cases of `AllCase` and **this** routine you can run in 2 separate threads:

```
public void doEverything(int browserIndex)
{
    AllCase(0, browserIndex);
    AllCase(1, browserIndex);
}
```

and start the threads like this:

```
for(int j = 0; j < browser.Length;j++)
{
    int brInd = j;
    Thread t= new Thread(()=>doEverything(brInd));
    t.Start();
}
```

you could also pass the entire browser object to the method and pass it further down to `OpenNRowsInData` and use it there

Comment: Like your comment, I want both browsers at the same time execute function `AllCase()`. In C#, when using multiple threads, I usually receive a process is a success all mission and the remaining Thread will be fails. Is that first process edit values of a variable before other Thread can tried to access to this?

Comment: actually in your case it does. it overwrites the `stepRun[idx] = 1;`. But your parallel approach is not tackling the two browsers it tackles the two cases of `AllCase`

Comment: You awesome. Thank you very much @mongzhu.