# UI not responsive when using Thread

Tags: c#, multithreading

I was using `Thread` to start two functions `AllCase` and run them in parallel.

```
Thread t1, t2;
t1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(AllCase))
{
    Name = "Thread1"
};
t1.Start();

t2 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(AllCase))
{
    Name = "Thread2"
};
t2.Start();
t1.Join();
t2.Join();
```

When `Thread` starts, I can't interact with the UI of application.

I read using [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx).

But I want to get `Name = "Thread1"` to use, like this:

```
int idx = int.Parse(Thread.CurrentThread.Name.Replace("Thread", "")) - 1;
```

The values `idx` to know this process[idx] to easy manipulate.

And `BackgroundWorker` is not working correctly in my case.

So, have any method to resolve my problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

remove these two lines:

```
t1.Join();
t2.Join();
```

and your GUI should become responsive again. Unless of course you have to wait for the methods to be completed in this order, but then you don't really need to use threads.

Comment: It's working. Remove two line will appear issues with my code. But I will fix. Thank you very much.

Comment: you are welcome. Out of curiosity, why do you use join to wait for the threads to finish?

Comment: In my case, `t1` will collect a data and `t2` need this data to process. But I read your comment: `Unless of course you have to wait for the methods to be completed in this order, but then you don't really need to use threads.`. and I understand it. Thanks @mongzhu.

Comment: Can you help me on this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38821739/how-to-create-n-object-base-on-datatable-rows-count-in-c